# Ubuntu 16.04.2: Excessive DHCPDISCOVER in syslog

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, dhclient, nmcli

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 server with 5 network interfaces (eth0-eth4).

The server started with 4 static interfaces.

ETH0,2 = WANs (with static public ips)

ETH3 = WAN (with static private ip)

ETH1 = LAN (with static private ip)

This was working fine, until i added the fifth card (eth4), which has a dynamic public ip, obtained through DHCP (lease time is 7200 sec). The DHCP server is running on the router that the ISP provided, and assigns ip to eth4 (i have no access to this router).

My problem is, that the /var/log/syslog file gets filled up very quickly with DHCPDISCOVER messages. Example:

```
Apr 25 07:36:49 proxy01 dhclient[36246]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x71437738)
Apr 25 07:36:50 proxy01 dhclient[36814]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x52470774)
Apr 25 07:36:52 proxy01 dhclient[36002]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x3003c736)
Apr 25 07:36:53 proxy01 dhclient[36814]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x72c16a08)
Apr 25 07:36:53 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6880636b)
Apr 25 07:36:56 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x6880636b)
Apr 25 07:36:57 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xbcb17169)
Apr 25 07:36:58 proxy01 dhclient[36814]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x31b2863a)
Apr 25 07:36:59 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x37d8972a)
Apr 25 07:37:00 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x6880636b)
Apr 25 07:37:00 proxy01 dhclient[35175]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xc75a4136)
Apr 25 07:37:01 proxy01 dhclient[36246]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x71437738)
Apr 25 07:37:02 proxy01 dhclient[36002]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x3003c736)
Apr 25 07:37:02 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x37d8972a)
Apr 25 07:37:04 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xbcb17169)
Apr 25 07:37:05 proxy01 dhclient[36246]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x7b70d96a)
Apr 25 07:37:06 proxy01 dhclient[45842]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x37d8972a)
Apr 25 07:37:07 proxy01 dhclient[36814]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x72c16a08)
Apr 25 07:37:07 proxy01 dhclient[36814]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x31b2863a)
Apr 25 07:37:09 proxy01 dhclient[36814]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x52470774)
Apr 25 07:37:10 proxy01 dhclient[35175]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xc75a4136)
```

My current /etc/network/interfaces looks like this (these ips aren't real):

```
auto lo eth1 eth0 eth2 eth3 eth4

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address 103.25.92.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 103.25.92.255
    network 103.25.92.0
    post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
    post-up ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables.up.rules

iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.1.2.3
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    broadcast 10.1.255.255
    network 10.1.0.0
    dns-nameservers 10.1.3.253 10.1.3.254 8.8.8.8
    dns-domain domain.local

iface eth2 inet static
    address 105.99.22.34
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    broadcast 105.99.22.39
    network 105.99.22.32
    up ip route add 195.199.255.195/32 via 105.99.22.38

iface eth3 inet static
    address 10.10.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    broadcast 10.10.1.3
    network 10.10.1.0
    gateway 10.10.1.1

iface eth4 inet dhcp
```

**ps aux | grep dhclient** shows 6 instances of dhclient running:

```
root     35175  0.0  0.0  16128  2860 ?        Ss   ápr24   0:03 dhclient -v
root     36002  0.0  0.0  16128  2844 ?        Ss   ápr24   0:03 dhclient -v
root     36246  0.0  0.0  16128  2960 ?        Ss   ápr24   0:03 dhclient -v
root     36814  0.0  0.0  16128  2896 ?        Ss   ápr24   0:03 dhclient -v
root     45842  0.0  0.0  16128  2904 ?        Ss   ápr24   0:03 dhclient -v
root     50187  0.0  0.0  16128  2964 ?        Ss   ápr24   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth4.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth4.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth4.leases eth4
```

Network Manager is also running and every NIC has a configured profile, but **nmcli c show --active** shows no active connections.

I need some help to get rid of the excessive DHCPDISCOVER entries in the syslog file and stop running dhclient altogether on static interfaces.

Comment: You could block port 68 on the static interfaces.

Comment: That didn't stop dhclient sending out DHCPDISCOVER broadcasts.